# Run a python in command (kali) with "run" on gdb-peda$

Tags: linux, gdb

While debugging a program under gdb with `gdb-peda` installed, I need to pass args to the binary using output from something like python.

Why I am not getting `AAAAA`?

```
gdb-peda$ b doSomthing
gdb-peda$ run  python -c 'print "A"*(5)'
```

I got the same text: `python -c 'print "A"*(150)'` as an output but I want to print  `AAAAA`

I think formatting mistake!? Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "run"

```
python -c 'print "A"*(5)'
```

prints:

AAAAA

Answer (score 0):

To pass args to a binary using a program such as python use normal bash evaluation. On bash this works

```
$ echo $(python -c "print('ABC'*3)")
ABCABCABC
```

Similarly under gdb console

```
r  $(python2 -c 'print "A"*(58))
```